# Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'swpdoc': /var/www/swpdoc/swpdoc/wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am getting this error radomaly (not always)

```
Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'swpdoc': 
    /var/www/swpdoc/swpdoc/wsgi.py
```

Here is my file **httpd.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/swpdoc/swpdoc/wsgi.py
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /var/www/swpdoc/swpdoc>
<Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-home=/var/www/swpdoc/venswpdoc python-
path=/var/www/swpdoc
WSGIProcessGroup swpdoc
```

Any help would be appreciated. Loading the index page taking so long and sometimes i get timeout errors.

I am also using `whoosh`.

Comment: What is Timeout set to in your Apache configuration. Likely your requests are taking longer than that value to respond.

Comment: There is no Timeout  setup. It should be default.

Comment: Which is likely 300 seconds. How long do your requests take? In access log what does it show for time of the request of log format is set up with time taken.

Comment: Not able to locate that here is the output . Really appreciate your help.      [16/Nov/2017:14:04:15 -0800] "GET /swpdocs/ HTTP/1.1" 504 247 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/537.36"

Comment: As mentioned, addition of time may need to be added. That is done using custom log format. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html You must at least have an idea of how long requests take before timeout, or is this just random messages in logs and not something you can reproduce? Are you using any sort of web application monitoring such as Datadog or New Relic?